# как сформировать Json Result перекрестных таблиц

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core

Есть три модели:

Компания:

```
public class Contractor
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ReportWork> ReportWorks { get; set; }
    }
```

Отчеты:

```
public class Report
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }       
        public string Name { get; set; }        
        public ICollection<ReportWork> ReportWorks { get; set; }
    }
```

Отчеты в работе:

```
public class ReportWork
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ReportStatus { get; set; }        
        public int ReportId { get; set; }
        public virtual Report Reports { get; set; }
        public int ContractorId { get; set; }
        public virtual Contractor Contractors { get; set; }        
    }
```

Как сформировать JsonResult следующей таблицы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я понимаю как это сделать в Razor:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>

            @foreach (var it in ViewBag.Report)
            {
            <th>
                @it.Name
            </th>
            }
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </th>

                @foreach (var it in ViewBag.Report)
                {
                    @if (item.ReportWorks.SingleOrDefault(c => c.ReportId == it.Id) != null)
                    {
                        <th>
                            @item.ReportWorks.SingleOrDefault(c => c.ReportId == it.Id).ReportStatus
                        </th>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <th>
                            Not
                        </th>
                    }
                }
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Но как сделать тоже самое в Json
по сути сформировать таблицу с N количеством столбцов.

```
[HttpGet]
        public JsonResult ()
        {
             var events = from e in _context.Contractor
                         from p in _context.ReportWork
                         select new
                         {
                             id = e.Id,
                             name = e.Name,
                             //Добавить сюда столбики с отчетами
                         };
            var rows = events.ToArray();

            return Json(rows);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно создать новый класс ReportViewModel, в него включить необходимые поля из разных таблиц. Далее запросом

```
IQueryable<ReportViewModel> result = (
        from company in db.Contractor
        join report in db.Report on company.Id equals report .Id
        join (если нужна еще одна таблица)
        where  здесь можно задать условие для выборки
        select new ReportViewModel
        {
            id = company.Id,
            name = report.Name,
            // и так далее по всем полям в ReportViewModel

        });
```

Comment: Да это работает если количество отчетов постоянно, а если оно меняется. В этом и смысл что коллекция должна быть динамичной. То есть сегодня в таблице может быть 5 столбцов, завтра 3 и т.д.